# Помогите решить проблему настройки Git - Unsupported SSL backend channel

Tags: git, github, ssl, openssl, git-push

При попытке запушить папку в гитхаб стал выдавать ошибку...
Unsupported SSL backend channel. Supported SSL backends -secure-transport,openssl
Возможно ошибочно была введена какая-то настройка git config ssl verify false..
Также теперь стало выскакивать окно, которое запрашивает пароль для входа на гитхаб

Comment: Покажите вывод `git remote -v` и `ping github.com`

Comment: Пока проблема разрешилась, вводом пароля на систему Мак. Всплывало окошко, что git credential osxkeychain хочет использовать информацию, хранящуюся в GitHub в вашей связке ключей. Хотя до этого пароль не запрашивал.